# ¿Cómo contar el número de valores que empiezan con un número en pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame `df`:

```
df=
         codigo
 1       901452   
 2       904443   
 3       071111   
 4       360102   
 5       891201   
 6       893420
```

Lo que necesito es determinar la frecuencia de aparición en la columna `codigo` teniendo en cuenta los dos primeros valores del número. En este caso la respuesta seria:

```
     07      1
     36      1   
     89      2  
     90      2
```

Yo utilice la siguiente línea: `df.codigo.value_counts()`pero cuenta los valores completos, no se como ajustarlo para que lo haga teniendo en cuenta solo los dos primeros números.

Además intente primero aplicar un filtro booleano revisando si iniciaba con los números para luego hacer el conteo, pero al realizar la primera parte con la siguiente instrucción para cada número posible`df['codigo'].astype(str).str.startswith('89')` todos me salian falsos.

Agradezco en lo que me puedan colaborar

Comment: Cómo usaste la última línea que mostraste? a mi si me funciona perfectamente... O a lo mejor tus números tienen espacios? en ese caso intenta poner `strip()` entre `str` y `startswith` (`str.strip().startswith('89')`)

Comment: Tienes razón, no me había dado cuenta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear una nueva columna (`codigo_short` en el ejemplo) con los dos primeros caracteres y calcular la frecuencia en base a eso:

```
df["codigo_short"] = df["codigo"].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[:2])

df_grouped = df.groupby("codigo_short").size()
```

Esto te da el dataframe `df_grouped`, que tiene esta forma (en base al ejemplo que diste):

```
codigo_short
36    1
71    1
89    2
90    2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta!